# Swift Animate lines with dots

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation

I have created multiple circles (points) using CAShapeLayer and multiple lines connecting to those circles.  Then i animate those circles.  what i want to do is animate connected lines along with dots. But only circles are animating not the lines.  How can i achieve this?  is there a way to update lines position?`

`

```
 var points: [CAShapeLayer] = []

let positions: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 70, y: 100),
                            CGPoint(x: 140, y: 100),
                            CGPoint(x: 210, y: 100),
                            CGPoint(x: 70, y: 200),
                            CGPoint(x: 140, y: 200),
                            CGPoint(x: 210, y: 200)]


var lines:[CAShapeLayer] = []

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    createPoints()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }





func createPoints(){

    for (index,position) in positions.enumerated() {
        let point = CAShapeLayer()
        point.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10), cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
        point.frame = CGRect(x: position.x, y: position.y, width: 10, height: 10)

        point.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        points.append(point)

        view.layer.addSublayer(points[index])
     }
        animatePosition(point: points[0])

        drawLines()
}

func drawLines(){
    for (index,_) in positions.enumerated() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

             //Not completed
            //set line's start position to dots position
            path.move(to: points[index].position)

            //set line's end position to dots position
            path.addLine(to: points[index+1].position)

        let line = CAShapeLayer()
        line.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
        line.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        line.lineWidth = 1
        line.strokeStart = 0
        line.path = path.cgPath
        lines.append(line)
        view.layer.addSublayer(line)
    }
}



func animatePosition(point: CAShapeLayer) {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")

    animation.fromValue = [10, 10 ]
    animation.toValue = [100, 100]
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity
    animation.isAdditive = true

    point.add(animation, forKey: "pointStart")
   // line.add(animation, forKey: "positionLine")
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()

}
```

[image]

What i want is some thing like this:
[image]

Comment: you want to show the seven dots initially (without animation) and then animate a line that joins all the dots? Is that what you want?

Comment: @JenJose Thank you for the reply, i have updated the question with an animated gif. That is what i want to accomplish. Please suggest me a way

Comment: I don't think this is something which you can do with Beizier paths. Becuase the beizier path points are drawn in 2D and the gif cleary shows that the points are in 3D and are rotating there.  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190604/scnshape-with-bezier-path

Comment: Here is an example in iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740338/swift-how-to-convert-a-particle-network-js-animation-to-ios

Comment: @JenJose i doesn't have to be in 3D space.I only need the movement. basically move the lines along with the dots.

Comment: @E.Coms Thanks. ill have a look